# bare metal wicket/tomcat HelloWorld example

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I'm a wicket newbie and would like to deploy the simple well-known helloworld from wicket-examples but without IDE, ant or maven. What I've done:

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
         version="2.4">

    <display-name>Wicket Examples</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>applicationClassName</param-name>
          <param-value>HelloWorldApplication</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>HelloWorldApplication</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

HelloWorld.html:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <span wicket:id="message">Message goes here!</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

HelloWorld.java:

```
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.WebPage;
import org.apache.wicket.markup.html.basic.Label;

public class HelloWorld extends WebPage
{
  public HelloWorld()
  {
    add(new Label("message", "Hello World!"));
  }
}
```

HelloWorldApplication.java:

```
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

public class HelloWorldApplication extends WebApplication
{
    public Class getHomePage()
    {
        return HelloWorld.class;
    }
}
```

wicket-HelloWorld.war:

```
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/web.xml
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorldApplication.class
WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld.class
WEB-INF/classes/HelloWorld.html
WEB-INF/lib/
WEB-INF/lib/wicket-1.4.15.jar
WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api.jar
```

I'm not sure if I need slf4j-api.jar for this simple example

When deployed to tomcat http://localhost:8080/wicket-HelloWorld/ gives:

The requested resource () is not available

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Take a look at the tomcat logs to see if sth is wrong when you start tomcat. Copy-paste the error/exception if you see anything

Comment: Can you post the log (`catalina.out`)? Maybe the problem is in your `server.xml` or your deployment.

Answer (score 1):

I've been able to make it work:

1.- I added slf4j-jdk14.jar. Manning Wicket in action bonus chapter 15 was wrong. It tells only to add slf4j-api.jar

2.- wicket-1.4.15.jar MUST BE in WEB-INF/lib. Trying to include it in catalina.properties under shared.loader or $CATALINA_BASE/lib doesn't work for me; despite some webs recommending these places as alternatives to include libraries at runtime.

I've found almost no documentation to build wicket apps using only javac. I think somebody experienced enough should write a little HOW-TO. You're almost forced to use Maven to program even the simplest application in wicket

Regards and thanks to all for the help

Francesc

Comment: 1.- Maybe because [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder) didn't default to a NOP logger in those days and the logged message helped you to fix it. 2.- It should work from `$TOMCAT_HOME/common/lib`, like [SLF4J](http://slf4j.org/codes.html#release) does.

Comment: 1.- According to SLF4J docs:
"As of SLF4J version 1.6.0, if no binding is found on the class path, then slf4j-api will default to a no-operation implementation discarding all log requests"
thus since in Manning version is older, should have advised to include a binding

2.- I DO CONFIRM that wicket-1.4.15.jar doen't work in $TOMCAT_BASE/lib where catalina.properties is:

common.loader=${catalina.base}/lib,...

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what is wrong with your application. I created a quick sample as follows to test the configuration:

```
$ mvn archetype:generate
```

Choosing `wicket-archetype-quickstart` (189 on my machine), version 1.4.15...

```
$ mvn tomcat:run
```

Browsing to `http://localhost:8080/wicket` and the application works like a charm.

```
$ mvn package
$ cd target/wicket-1.0-SNAPSHOT/WEB-INF/lib
```

And these are the libraries required:

- log4j-1.2.14.jar
- slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
- slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
- wicket-1.4.15.jar

Sources:

```
$ cd src/main
$ tree
```

And my source structure is:

```
.
|-- java
|   `-- com
|       `-- blogspot
|           `-- nurkiewicz
|               |-- HomePage.html
|               |-- HomePage.java
|               `-- WicketApplication.java
|-- resources
|   `-- log4j.properties
`-- webapp
    `-- WEB-INF
        `-- web.xml
```

I understand you don't want to use maven (great if you are learning and trying to do anything from scratch), but without any further information I can only advice you to look at my working example above. First of your libraries set seems to be incomplete.

Comment: log4j-1.2.14.jar and slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar are only needed if Apache's log4j logging is used (according to "wicket in action" chapter 15). Nonetheless adding the two laking libraries doesn't help.

Yes, I'm trying to do all from scratch (just to learn) and tought somebody has already tried before.

Can you detail java/html sources and web.xml? Thanks

Comment: OK, does your application startup properly? Do you see `Started Wicket version 1.4.15 in development mode` message on Tomcat console? If not, are there any exceptions?

Comment: needed log libraries are: slf4j-api.jar slf4j-jdk14.jar
(java.util.logging bindings)
but I get exceptions:
_java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory_
It's strange since it's included in slf4j-api.jar.
Ideas?

Comment: Just an idea: perhaps I've to recompile wicket with my java-6-openjdk compiler

Comment: Using maven archetype as a starting point for a "hello world" is all kinds of wrong, since assuming that maven is even being used is a huge jump from having nothing.

Comment: @Esko no it's not wrong, it's explicitly recommended: http://wicket.apache.org/start/quickstart.html (+1 to balance ignorant downvote)

Comment: @Sean My downvote was far from ignorant, Maven is the less greener grass side of the fence. Also if something works well for a simple Hello World but requires you to read multiple books and write thousands of lines of XML just to get something a bit more complex to work when you're actually supposed to start doing something productive with the tool you just should steer away. Maven's only good merit is that it was the first that tried to solve the whole s/w project structure management issue, but that doesn't mean it should still be recommended to anyone.

Comment: @Esko while I respect your informed opinion, I disagree with you in all points. a) maven has its shortcomings, but it's the best build tool out there. Both it's dependency management and it's convention over configuration approach are extremely practical (and all other build tools that don't suck now use maven's dependency concept). if the XML is too verbose, check out polyglot maven (or: use the m2eclipse pom editor, which is awesome). b) IMHO maven AND ant should be installed on all Java developer machines. Given that, there is no way in any other tool I know of that gets you up and ...

Comment: ... running as fast as the above mvn archetype code does. It's the simplest way I know of to create a complete working project from scratch. c) even if maven where as bad as you seem to think it is, that wouldn't justify a downvote for recommending the exact practice the framework authors recommend. But I have strong feelings about downvotes in General. On this site, smart people invest a lot of their time. Upvotes are the only reward they get for that. That's why I save up downvotes for crap answers, not for recommendations of technologies I don't like. But that's my downvoting philosophy ...

Comment: ... and you are entitled to have your own.